# meteor on openShift node version

Tags: node.js, meteor, version, openshift

meteor (v0.6.6.3) on openShift, customized openShift nodeJS to 0.10.21, mongoDB 2.2

I try to get a meteor app running on openShift. I have upgrade the nodeJS from the openShift default 0.10.5 to nodeJS 0.10.21 because meteor needs this nodeJS version as minimum.

If i open a ssh shell to openShift and let give me the node version than it shows me correct my upgraded version of 0.10.21 ( node --version ).
But if i will start the meteor application they see a nodeJS version of 0.10.5 (console log out with 'process.version' ) and starts again, again, again...

Can someone point me to the direction where i can look what's happened or what i'm doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Have you found an appropriate cartridge?

Answer (score 1):

## Edit (06.aug.2014)

As of now openshift is running nodejs version **v0.10.25** which should be fine for running a meteor app. I am currently running one that is based on the **0.8.2/3** version.

## Outdated answer (20. jan. 2014)

I have found the following [repo](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift), that according to the description lets you use any custom nodejs version.

Note: I am trying it out as we speak and will report back.

### Edit

After 6 hours of trying out:

- 2 different app bootstraps ([ryanj](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift), [openshift](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/nodejs-custom-version-openshift))
- 3-4 different nodejs cartridges from this [repo](https://github.com/adfec/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs/network)

I gave up these approaches.

But made it work via the following steps:

1. I downgraded meteor to 0.6.5

   `meteor update --release 0.6.5`
2. Used demeteorizer to "bundle app"
3. Copied contents of folder into the openshift dir created by following [this tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/cloudy-with-a-chance-of-meteorjs)
4. Replaced `process.env.ROOT_URL` in meteorshim with

   `process.env.ROOT_URL = "http://" + (process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS || "localhost");`
5. Updated `MIN_NODE_VERSION` in `programs/server/boot.js` with:

   `var MIN_NODE_VERSION = 'v0.10.5';`
6. git push and app was up & running

Answer (score 1):

I 've prepared this "quickstart" solution,
it uses METEOR + NODE v0.10.24 (but it can be changed) 
with Meteor example LeaderBoard and it can be easy transformed to your real application.

I have tested on Meteor 0.7.0.1

see: https://github.com/vladka/openshift-meteor-leaderboard-customNode

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version of the software installed by a cartridge is not supported, but you can make a DIY app that has the version you want or roll you own nodejs cartridge with the version you want.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for answering. I'm absolute new to openShift. So i followed an artice about changing the node version with the MARKER. Are there a list of community catridges. I'm sure that i'm not alone who needs an actual node.js version.

Answer (score 0):

I created the openshift app using nodejs-0.10 instead of nodejs-0.6.

Then i followed this [repo](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift) as mentioned by Matyas.
As the final step, i added new openshift env variable, something like:

`rhc env add OPENSHIFT_youruniquestring_PATH_ELEMENT=/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxx/app-root/data/node-v0.10.29-linux-x64/bin -a yourAppName`

Please adjust the values above to match yours.

After that try to make some dummy changes to your source code, then commit and push.

Once finished, you should run on node 0.10.29.

It worked for me, my app now running on meteor 0.8.3 with node 0.10.29